# Issue command in screen without attaching

Tags: linux, sh, gnu-screen

I'm running a Minecraft server, I want to make an sh script that when run, will attach to a screen and issue commands to the server. This is especially useful for long commands that may need multiple other commands to run.

I've tried `screen -x zencraft/zencraft bash -c say test`. But that didn't work. Neither did `screen -x zencraft/zencraft bash -c echo -e "$(say test)"` (but I didn't expect that to work anyway, because putting commands in $() in an echo just runs it as bash.)

I'm clueless on what to do at this point.

Note: The screen is shared between users and zencraft owns the screen. This is why using `+x zencraft/zencraft` is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured this out myself, thanks to the help of some people.

`screen -S zencraft/zencraft -p 0 -X stuff 'command'` works. The `stuff` command is the key here - it actually does the magic of running the command, from what I know.